# Working with Facebook Authentication in a Development Environment

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

When working with facebook authentication in a client-side server side mode with OAuth2, is there any way to test it out while working with local development environments for the redirect uris?

Obviously you could specify your IP and route port 80 on that IP to your computer, but is there a more simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

you shouldn't have any problems developing a facebook app locally.
Just set the url's on facebook settings page to http://localhost/yourapp/ and work as usual.
All the OAuth procedures should work normally.

Comment: thanks for the response - but so? you pass facebook an auto url which it calls, how can facebook call ones localhost?

Comment: Facebook doesn't "call" your uri's they redirect your browser to them and your browser do know your localhost uri's. there are only couple of places facebook "call" your uri's like on Facebook Credits api etc in those places you'll need to route an external IP to your local computer in order to work with those APIs

Answer (score 0):

In my experience so far, you can use the same facebook application for dev, testing, staging, production, etc. The key (alluded to by [lnetanel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108242/lnetanel)) is that the app should have a distinct return URL configured for each environment. For example, I use devise+omniauth, and have the following in .../config/initializers/omnniauth.rb, which is used to construct return URLs:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  OmniAuth.config.full_host = "https://www.mydomain.com"
elsif Rails.env.test?
  OmniAuth.config.full_host = "https://www.stag.mydomain.com"
elsif Rails.env.development?
  OmniAuth.config.full_host = "https://localhost.mydomain.com"
end
```

Note, I have a habit of adding localhost.mydomain.com in my local /etc/hosts file so there are no cross domain issues during development, though that is probably not relevant here.