# Facebook Login + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise

I'm getting the following error when trying to sign into Facebook through my app (Development mode). I'm not using the same FB login as I did to create the app and I know I need to submit my app to FB for them to approve but I'm not at that stage yet, I just want to make sure it works with several different accounts. Any suggestions?

"Error
App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login."

Comment: register your app on facebook .. u will be given an id which you have to use for authentication

Comment: thanks a bunch for the tip, wasn't sure if they would approve since it's not actually live on a site? just locally on my computer

Comment: Is your app register on facebook app ??

Comment: I have not registered it yet because it's only in development mode, is this okay to register it from here?

Comment: you shouldn't have any problems developing a facebook app locally. Just set the url's on facebook settings page to http://localhost/yourapp/ and work as usual.
All the OAuth(gem) procedures should work normally.

Comment: see this link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716285/working-with-facebook-authentication-in-a-development-environment

Comment: under which setting am i posting localhost/myapp?

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, you can initially only use your Facebook app when logging in as the user who owns/created the app.  Once you make the app public on the Status and Review section of the app config. on Facebook, anyone can login in to it.  However, before it's public there are a couple of ways you can get other users to test it:

1. You can invite other Facebook users to test the app using the Add Testers button on the Role section of the app config.  I've found that it seems the users you invite have to be your Facebook friends (of course if they're not already your friends and they're your clients/bosses you may want to put them in a restricted friend list so they can't see your entire Facebook profile).
2. You can add special test users for the app using the `Test Users` 'tab' at the top of the Role section.  You can then log in to the app as these test users.  See https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/527/ and  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/35/ for more details.

Either way, the users you add add testers or the test users you create should no longer get the error message saying "The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login."  Everyone else still will until you make the app public (or until you invite them to be test users of course!).